# Whats the difference between Ubuntu 11.04 and Pinguy 11.04

Tags: 11.04

System wise are they not the same? I know Pinguy has add-ons but works just like Ubuntu under the hood.

Comment: This question is sort off not off topic. A user can ask what are the main differences between Ubuntu and a Ubuntu spin off that has no support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much, PinguyOS is based on Ubuntu, works with mostly Ubuntu packages and should almost be identical as Ubuntu under the hood. But it is not developed or supported by Ubuntu.

The main differences between PinguyOS and Ubuntu are

- PinguyOS uses a heavy tweaked GNOME3 desktop
- Installs by default codecs that are not included by Ubuntu due to their licenses
- It contains by default a lot of software that is not installed in Ubuntu by default explaining the minimum 1.6Gb DVD download necessary to install it

In the end, other than licenses and personal packages choice, some visual tweaks and scripts, it is not different from Ubuntu.

But since Ask Ubuntu only deals with official Ubuntu or Ubuntu flavors PinguyOS is off topic for most questions here.

Comment: *Not welcome* is not the meaning, **not supported** should be the correct idea. There is a general site for Linux where you can ask such questions against any distributions that are not supported. For more information please read the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) from Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Correct.  Only official ubuntu derivatives such as xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu, edubutu are answerable on this site.  You can ask pinguy questions on the Unix & Linux StackOverflow site.

Comment: Only the official ones are supported here. Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Edubuntu and Ubuntu. Derivatives of Ubuntu (Not worked by the ubuntu developers or an extension of them) are not dealt here. Derivatives (Childs of Ubuntu) are: Mint, Pinguiyos and any other that derives from Ubuntu but is not worked by the ubuntu community.

Comment: If they are installed in Ubuntu? Yeah sure, why not? Features, bug reports, anything that cannot be handled in lauchpad? No, not really. Basically: installation via a PPA, removal, restoring previous packages, fixing broken packages, etc are on topic and should be fine to ask.

Comment: As long as you did it in Ubuntu and you can recover to Ubuntu (if needed) there is not issue here, look, [we even have a tag for it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cinnamon). Why don't you share your concerns or doubts in chat with us? Either join the [general room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) or invite any of the users for a 1 on 1 talk to get all those doubts out of your chest ;) btw: welcome to Ask Ubuntu.